# module.exports scope and node-mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have database.js file that connects to db and manage connections I export connection and reuse it in my app

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: cfg.mysql.host,
        user: cfg.mysql.user,
        password: cfg.mysql.pass,
        database: cfg.mysql.db,
        port: cfg.mysql.port
    });


    function handleDisconnect() {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, cnt) {
    module.exports.connection = cnt;
    });

    pool.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    };

    handleDisconnect();
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
      console.error(err.code);
    if(err.code === "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST")
    handleDisconnect();
      console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
    });
```

app.js

```
    var db = require('./database');
     app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        db.connection.query('SELECT * from table', function(err, result) {
           console.log(result);
          });
        }
```

This works fine. My problem is when the mysql server disconnect. I handle this error by recalling the handleDisconnect() function to get a new connection. However, when that happens the connection is undefined in my app.js when I navigate to my browser /test

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put the connection back into pool following each query on your database server
here's an example

**db.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'test',
  port: 8889
});

exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};
```

**app.js**

```
var db = require('./db');
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(!err){
            connection.query('SELECT * from users' , function(err, rows) {
                var users = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    users += rows[i].name + "<br />";
                }
                connection.release(); // always put connection back in pool after last query
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                response.write("<html>");
                response.write("<head>");
                response.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
                response.write("</head>");
                response.write("<body>");
                response.write(users);
                response.write("</body>");
                response.write("</html>");
                response.end();
           });
        }else{
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            response.write("<html>");
            response.write("<head>");
            response.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
            response.write("</head>");
            response.write("<body>");
            response.write(err.toString());
            response.write("</body>");
            response.write("</html>");
            response.end();
        }
    });
});
server.listen(9999);
console.log("Server is listening localhost:9999");
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: See first comment below for a correction on my [mis]understanding of the problem. I am leaving this response around, rather than deleting it, since it touches on more than one issue.**

You cannot keep reassigning to module.exports. It won't work because the export occurs only once at require() time (in fact, I suspect your code above works at all only because pool.getConnection executes synchronously i.e., assigning to module.exports in a callback is not typically safe). Here's what's going on:

In app.js you do: `var db = require('./database');`

This stores a reference not to module.exports (of database.js) but to the object that is assigned to module.exports (i.e., the connection object). When that object is destroyed because of a disconnect the variable "db" in app.js refers to nothing (note that node-mysql docs are clear that you cannot reuse the connection object). What you really want to do is to return a new connection object to app.js but that's not possible because app.js calls require only once.

I understand that you want to hide connection re-establishment from app.js. One way to do that is to wrap the node-mysql connection object in your own database.js object and return the latter to app.js. This wrapped object can obtain a connection from the pool when it's query() method is called and then call the query() method of the obtained connection. So on.

Comment: The connection isn't assigned to `module.exports`, it's assigned to `module.exports.connection`, so that should work just fine (although I agree the current setup is a bit dubious).

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking of `pool.getConnection` in `handleDisconnect` is throwing an error. Since you haven't built in a timeout before reconnecting in case a connection gets lost, the chances are that immediately calling `pool.getConnection` will fail because of the same problem.

Also, between the moment that the connection gets lost and `handleDisconnect` reconnecting, any incoming HTTP requests can't perform database queries so should check if `db.connection` is actually valid before trying to run a query.

That, or you need to handle errors in your Express routes too, for instance with an error handler route (which should be placed somewhere last in your route/middleware setup):

```
// middleware setup
...
// routes setup
...
// finally:
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.send(500, err.message); // or whatever you want to send back in case of errors.
});
```